# Por que siempre me devulve un resultado null? En un grid view android

Tags: android

Al intentar acceder al view me devulve que siempre es nulo

```
View v = null;
v = (View) gridView.getItemAtPosition(posicion);
```

Comment: agrega el método completo por favor.

Comment: Por que en esa posicion no hay vista q exista, para tener una posicion real, tienes que obtener la primera vista y la ultima visible, los layout manager tiene varias funciones para tu logica para obtener las vistas q existen , una vez obtengas una vista visible por ej la primera , le pides la posicion pasandole la vista. Cheka todas las funciones que tiene.